# Data Structure with inheritance. Problems initializing

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance

I need make a class, let's say `FineStack`, who should declare a structure able to manage different kind of Fines ( `LightFine`, `SeriousFine` ). The superclass for both is `Fine`.

The question is, do I really need templates? I thought it was not necessary, so this is what I thought:

-> declare `Fine *fines`; ( kind-of array of fines? ) And ... creating an array of `Fine`'s objects (the superclass), it should be able to manage both `LightFine` and `SeriousFine` objects.

-> The problem is. How should I declare it? `Fine` should be an abstract class, so no instances could be created (instances should be either `LightFine`'s or `SeriousFine`'s ).

I got stuck with this, since I don't find the way to get it. I've read in multiple questions here in Stackoverflow, that you guys usually suggest to use `std::vector` , which makes you easier to manage this kind of stuff.

Should I go in that way and forget about the original idea?

I need a structure which should be able to handle any object from both subclasses, in any order (let's say .. 3 `LightFine` and 2 `SeriousFine` ... or alternatively each other from the start to the end of the structure ... whatever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would like to point you in the right direction and not just give you the whole shebang. If this doesn't help, please ask about what's troubling you:

Although `Fine` cannot be instantiated, you can point to it, so:

```
Fine* f1 = new LightFine();
Fine* f2 = new SeriousFine();
```

are both legal, because `LightFine` is-a `Fine` and `SeriousFine` is-a `Fine`.

**Edit:** I see this is not clear yet. If you read the above you can see that I can hold a pointer `Fine*`, yet have it "secretly" point to either `LightFine` or `SeriousFine`. That means, If I were to keep a bunch of `Fine*` pointers, some of them could be `LightFine` and some `SeriousFine`. i.e, I can do this:

```
Fine** fines = new Fine*[5];
f[0] = new LightFine();
f[1] = new SeriousFine();
...
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    std::cout << fines[i]->toString() << std::endl;
}
```

and the output would be:

> a light fine
>
> a serious fine
>
> ...

if you *do* want to use a vector, it too should be of type `vector<Fine*>` and **not** `vector<Fine>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time trying to help me. Let's hit the code one more time after your useful words ;) Excuse me for my poor English!

Comment: And how should look like FineStack's constructor? I try to initialize there the "fines" structure, without any success. Shouldn't I alocate enough space for all the Fine pointers?

Comment: @Carlos see my edited answer. I suspect you're initializing an array of `Fine` instead of `Fine*`.

Comment: :-) You've suspected well, and answered and helped me better! :-) Now it's all crystal-clear, I've learnt a lot ;) Thank you very much Amir.

Comment: ieph, i thought it was only enabled for registered users ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have an array of Fines or a vector of fines because the Fine class is abstract (and it should really be).

The solution is to use either an array of pointers (like `Fine **fines` and `fines = new Fine*[whatever-size-you-need]`) or a vector of pointers (like `std::vector<Fine*> fines`). After that, you can instantiate any subclass of Fine with `new` and it will be implicitly upcasted to `Fine*` when you put it into the array/vector.

And you certainly don't need templates here, unless you have another (unrelated) reason to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Revised answer after my first had errors:

Will both `LightFine` and `SeriousFine` implement only the interface from `Fine`, or will they have additional methods that the `FineStack` will need to know about?

If the `FineStack` will only interact with the `Fine` objects using methods defined in `Fine`'s interface, then I don't see a problem with your array approach, as long as you use `Fine** fines` (i.e. an array of pointers to `Fine`s). Although, I'd tend to use a `std::vector<Fine*>` instead.

(I did have a comment here about dynamic_cast, but I've removed it after a couple of commentors suggested it was dangerous advice).

Comment: really, the single point of the inheritance is that toString() method is declared as abstract in Fine class, and each of LightFine and SeriousFine has the proper toString() overrided.

Comment: ... and you should be able to get the proper output (say: invoke dynamically the proper toString() ) through polimorfism.

Comment: No problems then :) Sounds like a textbook use of inheritance!

Comment: Yeah, that's what it is ;) I'm preparing my c++ practical exam for the Uni, and still get stuck with some concepts ( 1st time I've ever struggled with C++ ) ... thanks Toby! Let's try all the stuff and how it reacts :P

Comment: @Toby, `vector<Fine>` will cause object slicing and undefined behaviour -- please see my comment on his answer.  Also, `dynamic_cast` should always be a last resort -- normally, whenever you need type-specific behaviour, you should call a virtual method that is implemented differently in each subclass.  -1 for now.

Comment: Yep, my bad, I left a * out of my vector and array definitions. That's all though, everything else I said is correct.

Comment: @Toby, can I suggest changing `std::vector<Fine>` to `std::vector<Fine*>` instead of just adding the "Edit" line at the bottom; removing the mention of EnabrenTane's incorrect answer; and removing the whole paragraph about `dynamic_cast`, which is poor advice.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, polymorphism (the ability to have the same code work with objects of multiple different subclasses of a given parent class) is accomplished with **pointers and references** to base classes, not base class types themselves.  If you come from a language like Java this might be confusing, because there all object references implicitly behave like pointers do in C++.

Ideally you should use `vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<Fine> >`.  The [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) does a good job explaining why `shared_ptr` simplifies memory management; TR1's `shared_ptr` is essentially the same as Boost's except that it [probably already comes with your compiler](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2010/05/24/smart-pointers-in-boost-tr1-cxx-x0/).

If you're content to do your own memory management, use `vector<Fine*>`.  **Don't** use `vector<Fine>` -- that will cause *object slicing*.

What is object slicing?  `LightFine` is (possibly) bigger than `Fine`, so it won't fit in the same amount of memory.  If you declared `Fine a; LightFine b; a = b;` this will compile, but the entire `LightFine` object won't fit in `a`, so just the `Fine` subobject of `b` will be copied.  Essentially the same thing happens when inserting a `LightFine` object into a `vector<Fine>`.

You won't be able to treat `a` as a `LightFine` object after that assignment, since its static type is just `Fine`, and all the `LightFine` "parts" have been discarded anyway.  Also, treating `a` as a `Fine` object can produce unexpected behaviour -- for example `Fine` might have an internal data field that is repurposed by `LightFine` and thus contains an out-of-bounds value when interpreted by `Fine`'s methods.

Answer (score -1):

sounds like you should go with `std::vector<Fine>`

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time trying to help me. Let's hit the code one more time after your useful words ;) Excuse me for my poor English!

Comment: -1 I'm afraid.  `vector<Fine>` will cause object slicing (or it would if it could compile; the fact that `Fine` is an abstract class will almost certainly create a compile-time error).  The right solution is to use pointers to `Fine`, or a vector of such (`vector<Fine*>`).

Comment: mmm ... interesting. I'm getting stuck on how to initialize the structure (alocating the memory for all the Fines):

Comment: for(int i=0; i<FineStack::MAX; i++){
 this->fines[i]=new Fine;
}

Comment: obviously that isn't allowed since Fine is an abstract class ... :S :S ... this is more tricky than I could ever expect! :P

Comment: when using,  " this->fines=new Fine[FineStack::MAX]; " in the constructor, it's the same history ... "abstract classes arrays are not allowed" it's what VS says.

Comment: You don't want an array of Fines since theyre abstract. You want an array of pointers to Fines.